# MS Access Delete Query when a field in one table matches a field in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, office365, sql-delete

I have two tables, Raw Data and County Addresses. If the Location field in the Raw Data table matches an Address field in the County Addresses table, I want Access to delete the record from the Raw Data table.

I entered the SQL below based on answers to similar posts, but I am still getting the error message "Could not delete from specified tables."

```
DELETE [Raw Data].*
FROM [Raw Data] 
INNER JOIN [County Addresses] 
ON [Raw Data].Location = [County Addresses].Address;
```

I need to ensure that, after the query is run, the Raw Data table excludes records for locations listed in the County Addresses table. I am using Microsoft 365, Access version 2211. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a DELETE action can work on only one table. Joining tables would require deleting from multiple tables at same time, which fails as you discovered. Use WHERE clause to specify records to delete. In this case, the condition is existence of data in another table. IN() function should serve this purpose. Consider:

`DELETE FROM [Raw Data] WHERE Location IN (SELECT Address FROM [County Addresses])`